# Force function to make assumptions about its input variables in Mathematica

Tags: evaluation, function-construction

I'm trying to force a Mathematica function to make an assumption about its input variables. In my case, I'm trying to define a function to return the pdf of a Gaussian. But let's use a simple toy case:

```
n[x_]:= x^(1/2);
```

Thus, n[x] returns

```
Sqrt[x]
```

However, n[x^2] returns

```
Sqrt[x^2]
```

While this is correct and fine in principle, in my case some of the variables (like variance) will always be positive and will always be real, thus the simplification

```
n[x^2] = x
```

is appropriate. I've tried many things like:

```
n[x_/; x > 0 && Element[x,Reals]]:=x^(1/2);
n[x_]:=Assuming[x > 0 && Element[x,Reals],FullSimplify[x^(1/2)]];
```

etc. The best I can get it to do is

```
n[x^2] = Abs[x];
```

When I want

```
n[x^2] = x;
```

Anyone have any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 9):

The following just works:

```
Assuming[x > 0, Simplify[Sqrt[x^2]]]

(*
==> x
*)
```

Your code:

```
n[x_/; x > 0 && Element[x,Reals]]:=x^(1/2);
n[x_]:=Assuming[x > 0 && Element[x,Reals],FullSimplify[x^(1/2)]];
```

doesn't work because the `x` that is passed  after a call of `n[x^2]` isn't `x` but `x^2`. So you're assuming `x^2>0` or `Element[x^2,Reals]`.

Answer (score 7):

Just to note there is a simple approach to this. You could define your function a bit differently:

```
n[x_] := PowerExpand[x^(1/2)]
```

which assumes that **x** is real and positive and gives:

```
n[x^2]
```

> x

Alternatively you can keep general:

```
n[x_] := x^(1/2)
```

But in calculations when need real-positive assumption on **x** use

```
PowerExpand[n[x^2]]
```

> x

Function `PowerExpand` takes `Assumptions` option which allow to do some neat stuff:

```
PowerExpand[Sqrt[z^2], Assumptions -> z < 0]
```

> -z

or with Assumptions->True, `PowerExpand` gives a universally correct expansion formula:

```
PowerExpand[Sqrt[z^2], Assumptions -> True]
```

> E^(I [Pi] Floor[1/2 - Arg[z]/[Pi]]) z

Read carefully **[Documentation Article](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PowerExpand.html)** - especially look through examples and *"more information"* tab:

Answer (score 4):

Here's a function which assumes that every symbol in the expression passed to it which is used as non-head is positive. Note however that this might not always be what you want.

```
n[x_]:=Assuming[And@@(#>0&/@Union@Cases[x,_Symbol,Infinity]),Simplify[x^(1/2)]]
```

With this definition, you get

```
n[a^2]
(*
==> a
*)
```

It works as follows:

`Cases[x,_Symbol,Infinity]` gives a list of all symbols in the expression passed through `x`, ignoring heads (so `Cases[Sin[omega*t],_Symbol,Infinity]` gives `{omega,t}`, not `{Sin,Times,omega,t}`). Applying `Union` to the result just is there to delete duplicates (strictly speaking it is not necessary). By mapping `#>0&` over this list you get a list of conditions `symbol > 0`, to which we just have to apply `And` in order to get the final condition.

The rest of the function definition is straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

You probably know about these:

```
x=.;
F:=PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x]

F:=PDF@NormalDistribution[0, 1]
```

How about this:

```
F[x_?NonNegative] := x^(1/2)
```