# Attaching persistent assumptions to symbol definition

Tags: evaluation, simplifying-expressions, assumptions

*Is it possible to attach assumptions to a symbol?* This relates to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4075/force-function-to-make-assumptions-about-its-input-variables-in-mathematica). Most of my work involves physical equations, i.e. there are basic assumptions on variables that will always hold true (in a physical sense).

My current example involves higher-order Laguerre Gaussian modes:

```
u[p_, m_, λ_, w_, R_, ψ_, ψ0_, r_, θ_] := 
Sqrt[(2 p!)/((1 + DiscreteDelta[0, m]) π (m + p)!)]
Exp[I (2 p + m + 1) (ψ - ψ0)]/w 
((Sqrt[2] r)/w)^m LaguerreL[p, m, (2 r^2)/w^2]
Exp[-I (2 π)/λ r^2/2 (1/R - I λ/(π w^2)) + I m θ]
```

For this example, consider $p=m=\psi=\psi 0=0$, which gives the electric field distribution for the basic Gaussian mode. I can get the mode intensity with (I'm sure there is a more concise way of writing the assumption):

```
Assuming[(And @@ (# > 0 && # ∈ Reals & /@ {λ, w, R, r, θ})) ~And~ 
    (r > 0 && r ∈ Reals && -π < θ <= π && θ ∈ Reals), 
    Abs[u[0, 0, λ, w, R, 0, 0, r, θ]]^2 //Simplify]
```

$$\frac{e^{-\frac{2 r^2}{w^2}}}{\pi  w^2}$$

Back to the question, *how can I define a function that "simplifies" without explicitly listing the assumptions every time a
I perform an algebraic operation on said function?* Looking at the previously linked question, I can define a function

```
v[p_, m_, λ_, w_, R_, ψ_, ψ0_, r_, θ_] := 
Assuming[(And @@ (# > 0 && # ∈ Reals & /@ {λ, w, R, r, θ})) ~And~ 
    (r > 0 && r ∈ Reals && -π < θ <= π && θ ∈ Reals), 
    u[p, m, λ, w, R, ψ, ψ0, r, θ]]
```

but the `Simplify` operation applies only to the definition, any operation such as

```
Abs[v[0, 0, λ, w, R, 0, 0, r, θ]]^2 // Simplify
```

$$\frac{e^{-2 \text{Re}\left[r^2 \left(\frac{1}{w^2}+\frac{i \pi }{R \lambda }\right)\right]}}{\pi  \text{Abs}[w]^2}$$
does not simplify.

Defining functions using pattern conditions, i.e. `f[a?Positive]:=...` do not allow for algebraic manipulation, as `f[a]` will remain unevaluated.

I am hesitant to use `$Assumptions`. Whilst it would work in this specific example, I can see several problems where I'd like to use the same approach, but setting global assumptions would cause other issues.

Comment: Could you be more specific about your reservations regarding `$Assumptions`?  It is of course the first answer that comes to mind.

Comment: It sets global assumptions. Another layer of things I set and then forget about.. :/

Comment: Have you looked at and considered the use of the [`TransformationFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TransformationFunctions.html) option for `Simplify`?

Comment: First time I heard about that option! It sort of does what I want, using a `simplify` function that calls `Simplify` with the appropriate `TransformationFunctions`.

Comment: Okay, I'll post that as an answer.  Don't rush to accept it; that may discourage someone from posting a better one.

Comment: Use Matlab.They declare all vars before symbolic calculations.

Comment: Variable declaration is a far cry from attaching assumptions, so the comment hardly addresses the question. (Maybe it was not meant to do so.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly more flexible approach is to use assumptions as an option for `u[..]`:

```
ClearAll[u, assuming, asmptns];
asmptns = And @@ 
Flatten@{(# > 0) & /@ {λ, w, R, r, θ}, (# ∈ Reals) & /@ {λ, w, R, r, θ}, -π < θ <= π};
Options[u] = {"assuming" -> asmptns};
u[p_, m_, λ_, w_, R_, ψ_, ψ0_, r_, θ_] := 
Sqrt[(2 p!)/((1 + DiscreteDelta[0, m]) π (m + p)!)] 
Exp[I (2 p + m + 1) (ψ - ψ0)]/w ((Sqrt[2] r)/w)^ m 
LaguerreL[p, m, (2 r^2)/ w^2] 
Exp[-I (2 π)/λ r^2/ 2 (1/R - I λ/(π w^2)) + I m θ];
Abs[u[0, 0, λ, w, R, 0, 0, r, θ]]^2 // 
Simplify[#, OptionValue[u, "assuming"]] &
```

gives

[image]

and, re-simplify with modified assumptions

```
SetOptions[u, "assuming" -> asmptns && (w == 2)];
Abs[u[0, 0, λ, w, R, 0, 0, r, θ]]^2 // 
Simplify[#, OptionValue[u, "assuming"]] &
```

to get

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use `$Assumptions` you may set the assumptions to a variable:

```
dom = And @@ (# > 0 &) /@ {λ, w, R, r} && -π < θ <= π  
(* λ > 0 && w > 0 && R > 0 && r > 0 && -π < θ <= π *)
```

Then call (Full)Simplify with these assumptions:

```
Abs[v[0, 0, λ, w, R, 0, 0, r, θ]]^2 //  Simplify[#, dom] &
```

giving: `1/π`

Answer (score 3):

The [`TransformationFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TransformationFunctions.html) option for `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` allows you to create custom simplification manipulations that can be used either in place of or in addition to the defaults.  Combined with `SetOptions` this can allow special handling of certain expressions by `Simplify` and/or `FullSimplify`.

Answer (score 3):

My proposal is elementary, and I am not answering your question in the form it has been asked. However, did you not think about custom assumptions or custom `Simplify`?  For example, in your case let us fix the assumptions:

```
assume = (And @@ (# > 0 && # ∈ Reals & /@ {λ, w, R, r, θ})) ~ And ~
    (r > 0 && r ∈ Reals && -π < θ <= π && θ ∈ Reals);
```

and make a custom `Simplify`:

```
mySimp[expr_] := Simplify[expr, assume];
```

Now with your function:

```
u[p_, m_, λ_, w_, R_, ψ_, ψ0_, r_, θ_] := 
Sqrt[(2 p!)/((1 + DiscreteDelta[0, m]) π (m + p)!)]
Exp[I (2 p + m + 1) (ψ - ψ0)]/w
((Sqrt[2] r)/w)^m LaguerreL[p, m, (2 r^2)/w^2]
Exp[-I (2 π)/λ r^2/2 (1/R - I λ/(π w^2)) + I m θ]
```

Let us simplify:

```
Abs[u[0, 0, λ, w, R, 0, 0, r, θ]]^2 // mySimp
(* =>  1/π  *)
```

This will work during the whole session. In a new session you need to only once execute a cell with this (and analogous) definition.

It seems me to be better than to attach the assumption to any variable. If I would attach a restriction to a variable, in 5 minutes I would need to use this variable outside of the just attached restriction :).