Simplifying Expressions Under Assumptions in Mathematica
In Mathematica, I want to evaluate the expression $\sqrt{\delta^2 - 1} $ under the global assumption that $ 0 < \delta < 1 $. I would like the expression to be displayed as $\sqrt{1 - \delta^2} \cdot i $. How can I set this global assumption so that the output reflects this transformation correctly?
$Assumptions = 0 < \[Delta] < 2/3 && \[Delta]^2 - 1 < 0
Assuming[0 < \[Delta] < 1, Simplify[Sqrt[\[Delta]^2 - 1]]]

the output $\sqrt{\delta ^2-1}$

Using Refine:
Refine[Sqrt[\[Delta]^2 - 1], 0 < \[Delta] < 1]


I Sqrt[1 - \[Delta]^2]

Or equivalent:
Block[{$Assumptions = 0 < \[Delta] < 1}, Refine[Sqrt[\[Delta]^2 - 1]]]


I Sqrt[1 - \[Delta]^2]


Simplify[ComplexExpand[Sqrt[\[Delta]^2 - 1], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}], 
Assumptions -> 0 < \[Delta] < 1]

(*I Sqrt[1 - \[Delta]^2]*)


@gnsylyj See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5260/attaching-persistent-assumptions-to-symbol-definition
